# FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS fails for small files

Tags: c++, windows, file, offset, sector

I am using FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS to obtain file's physical offset(sectors).
The problem I am facing is I am not able to get the sectors of files whose size is 1 kb or less.
I know record of files with size 1 kb or less is stored in the MFT itself.
Can someone help me to obtain the sectors of such files?
Any kind of help will be appreciated, it will be more better if someone can provide me with the sample code doing the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: NTFS objects (file, folder, stream, etc.) that is small enough to fit in its own MFT entry free space, will not have a physical cluster, thus `FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS` will fail. Length of object and hardlink presence are some of the things that affect an MFT entry free space.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. How can I read such file's sector(physical address) from MFT?

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the file $MFT to retrieve the physical location, the location is stored in the attribute 0x80. You can use winhex to open the raw disk and view the file records of these small files.